# How to get complete console output from remote machine via SSH

Tags: shell, npm, ssh, command-line, terminal

I have a normal bash script which deploys my locally developed application to a test server. The script looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh username@192.168.0.x "cd /my/directory/api && npm install"
ssh username@192.168.0.x "cd /my/directory/api && npm run build"
ssh username@192.168.0.x "cd /my/directory/api && npm run schema:drop"
ssh username@192.168.0.x "cd /my/directory/api && mysql -u username database_name < dump.sql"
```

Now I want to get the output of this commands on my locale terminal. But I only get some output when the commands fails. How can I get the complete output?

Answer (score 0):

Running repeated `ssh` commands to the same host is clumsy and inefficient anyway.

```sh
ssh username@192.168.0.x "
    set -e  # abort on any failure
    cd /my/directory/api
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run schema:drop
    mysql -u username database_name < dump.sql" >output.log 2&>1
```

Comment: Not entirely sure `set -e` will work in this mode; it will only exit the shell if it is not interactive. Unfortunately, I'm not in a place where I can test this. If this doesn't abort when it fails, you can change how the commands are passed in so that it's not interactive, or take out the `set -e` and instead end each line with `&&`